# Is it possible to install a Windows XP driver on Windows 98?

Tags: drivers, windows-98

I can't find a Windows 98 driver for my Epson SX130 printer. The oldest OS it has drivers for is Windows XP. I have medical equipment that only works on Windows 98, and no updates are available for my software,

Is there a way to use Windows XP drivers on Windows 98?

Comment: No, there is no way to install a windows XP driver or even Windows 2000 driver on a windows 98 installation

Comment: No you can't do that, because Windows 98 used a very different kernel (e.g. DOS). 2000 and XP are based on NT. Any chance you have another computer on your local network? You might be able to use that as a print server.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch even with a print server you'd still need some kind of driver. It's a tricky situation.

Comment: @nhinkle I didn't mean to imply otherwise. But it might be possible to do a PostScript compatible translation, e.g. with Samba. I don't have a Epson SX130, but I do have some old PostScript printers and they worked under Windows 98 (as far as I remember). Or maybe it supports PCL. IDK.

Answer (score 3):

No. The architecture and kernel of pre-NT windows was very different than NT.  Drivers are not compatible.

What you might try is finding a print to file option, then set up an automated script to then send the file across a network connection to a computer that is capable of printing the file.

You should do this over an internal only connection, as a window 95 computer should never be exposed to the internet.

Comment: i've already tried that  solution, but the software (of the equipments ) doesn't allow that, it prints directly to the printer

Comment: Find a virtual printer device that prints to file then.

Comment: Via WDM, some drivers can work on both 9x and NT versions of Windows, but generally only in a forward compatible way.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Model - Any device built since 2003-2004 or so is almost certainly not going to work.

Comment: That's likely going to be in the wrong direction. A driver written for Windows XP will be relying on more up to date access that simply doesn't exist in Windows 98. It might be remotely possible for a Windows 98 driver to work in XP. This is all moot, of course, as both operating systems are completely EOL by Microsoft and replacements should be actively sought.